# Provision new GCE from existing compute engine using gcloud

Tags: google-compute-engine

I have a situation here, I want to auto provision 2 GCE vms ( say A and B) from an exiting GCE (say C) and A, B and C machines should communicate to each other without asking any password (enable password less login). With gcloud utility, I am able to auto provision A and B from C but could not create password less login automatically. Tried with google's document of 'gcloud compute ssh' but my user was not able to log into without password.

Answer (score 2):

By default, all the GCE images use [private/public key pair](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance) for ssh authentication. You can enable password based authentication, however, its not recommended due to security reasons.

If you wish to ssh from one VM to another without providing the ssh keys, you can start `ssh-agent` on one VM to manage your keys. The steps are documented on this [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-instance#sshbetweeninstances) under the heading **Connecting to instances that do not have external IP addresses**.